# Algorithms/Techniques for rating website (PageRank aside)

Tags: algorithm, rank, pagerank

I'm looking for algorithms/techniques that are able to present the importance  of a a single webpage. Leaving PageRank aside, are there any other methods of doing such a rating based on content, structure and hyperlinks with each other?

I'm not only talking about the connection from www.foo.com to www.bar.com as PageRank does but also from www.foo.com/bar to www.foo.com/baz and so on (beside the fact of adapting PageRank for these needs)

*How do I "define" importance*: I think of importance in this context as "how relevant is this side to the user, as well as how important it is to the rest of the site".
E.g. A christmas raffle is announced on the startpage with only a single link leading to this site is more important to the user as well as to the site. An imprint, which has a link from every site (since it's mostly somewhere in the footer) is not important although it has many links to it. Imprint is also not important to the site as a "unit" since it doesn't give any real value for the page's puprpose (= giving information, selling products, a general service, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also [SALSA](http://www.cparity.com/projects/AcmClassification/samples/383041.pdf) which is more stable then HITS [so it suffers less from spam].

Since you are also interested in context of pages, you might want to have a look on Haveliwala's work on [topic sensitive page rank](http://research.taherh.org/pubs/topic-sensitive-pagerank-tkde.pdf)

Comment: Pretty nice papers you attached, I'm looking into them. Sound very interessting, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another famous algorithm is the [Hubs and Authorities (HITS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HITS_algorithm). Basically you classify your page as either a *Hub* (a page having a lot of outbound links) and *Authorities* (a page having a lot of inbound links).

But you should really define what you mean by importance. What does really important mean ? *PageRank* defines it with respect to the inbound links. That is *PageRank* definitions.

If you define *important* as having a photo, because you like photography. Then you could come up with an *important* metric like *number of photos in the page*. Another metric could be *the number of inbound links from a photography site* (like `flickr.com`, `500px`, ...)

Using your definition of *important*, you could use `1-(the number of inbound links divided by the number of pages on the site). This gives you a number between 0 and 1. 0 means not important and 1 means important.

Using this metric your imprint, which appears on all the pages of the site, has importance of 0. Your Christmas sale page, which has only one link to it, has importance almost 1

Comment: Good point, I added a description of what I consider "important". Will look into HITS as well. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I added a metric function for your description of "important". Not quite sure it is what you want though.